# How force NPM to get the last commit of package from repo with master?

Tags: git, npm

I have several packages inside a Gitlab and I need use this packages in my internal projects, NPM works perfectly with tags but I can not create a tag for each commit.

```
"dependencies": {
  "XX-alert": "git+http://git.domain.com/XX-platform/XX-alert.git",
  ...
}
```

Have any way to force NPM to re-download package from last commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the commit hash by appending it to the install command, e.g. for github

```
npm install github:<githubname>/<githubrepo>[#<commit-ish>]
```

So you replace the dependency path by

```
git+http://git.domain.com/XX-platform/XX-alert.git#commit-hash
```

and `npm install` to download it

Comment: So, if use the command `npm install git+http://git.domain.com/XX-platform/XX-alert.git` works too, but is very strange for me.

Comment: but like this each time you have to get the latest hash. and add it to your `package.json` this is not answered for this question.

Comment: I second that, I too want to npm to download latest hash, and not have to get it my self and update the package.json every time.